# Custom Lookup on VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

This is my VF Page.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">

<apex:form >

<apex:pageBlock title="{!account.Name}" >

<apex:pageblockSection >


<apex:inputField value="{!account.Account_Number__c}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!account.CustomerPriority__c}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!account.Active__c}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!account.SLA__c}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!account.Billing_Contact__c}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!account.Business_Contact__c}"/>


</apex:pageblockSection>

<apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>

</apex:pageBlock>




</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

My problem statement is when I invoke the "lookup" I can see it is showing all contacts regardless whether the contact is associated to the account or not.

[image]

I would like to display only those contacts belonging to that particular account.

Can someone point me some resources or provide me some highlevel guidelines as to how to achieve that ?

Comment: Does it have to be a lookup? You could query and create a list of Contacts at the Account in the controller/extension then display as a picklist on your VF page.

Comment: Yes that would suffice :)..All I need is a way to show the list of all Contacts under that particular account.

Comment: Are you using the same lookup field billing contact on account layout too? One easy way is to use lookup fileter and display on the contacts related to the account. This will restrict the contacts related to the account both on the VF Page and the account layout.If this not a problem easy way is to use lookup filters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use lookup filter. For more details refer to following link:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_lookup_filters_defining.htm